# Codeigniter 3 + php 5.6 + xampp + sqlserver 2008 + win7 64x

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, sql-server-2008

So sorry if this exists, but I'm having trouble with codeigniter 3, php 5.6, sqlserver 2008 and win7 64x.
I followed the steps from various sites, such as Rob's Area, also read a couple of questions in this site but still can't find the answer.

With php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll and php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll from SQLSRV32.EXE the error I was getting was:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/mycodeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php
>   Line Number: 436

Then downloaded Rob's sqlsrv_unofficial_3.0.2.2.zip and got this error:

> Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()
>   Filename: sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php Line Number: 144

The code I have in Codeigniter is:

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'port'  => '1433',
'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
'username' => 'myuser',
'password' => 'mypass',
'database' => 'mydb',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => TRUE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'autoinit' => TRUE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

Then used this one, this one worked, but can't call the results when querying.

```
 $db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => 'Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=mydb;',
'hostname' => '',
'username' => 'myuser',
'password' => 'mypass',
'database' => 'mydb',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

Please ideas?

Comment: what error shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll (afaik the current sqlsrv build should be ok, otherwise you've to take robs build)

After that try the following in your db-config

```
$db['default'] = array
(
    'dsn'   => 'sqlsrv:server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=mydb',
    'username' => 'myuser',
    'password' => 'mypass',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    ...
);
```

> 1433 is the current port - change it to your defined port - but i'm not sure if you need that

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much! It worked out with SQLSRV32.EXE dlls. At first I had an ODBC error, so I had to install ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server (msodbcsql.msi).

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention in case anyone comes looking for the same solution: the answer given by sintakonte says "172.0.0.1" obviously you need to change it to "127.0.0.1" or "localhost" :)